# Changing the image of the pictureBox in the code

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

In my project on WindowsForms (VS13) I have a **pictureBox**. How can I change the image of it in the code?

```
pictureBox1.Image = //???
```

For example, for the the **textBox** I can do it like:

```
richTextBox1.Text = someVariable.ToString();
```

The image are exists in my project's folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add the picture to you projects resources you can change the image like this

```
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.picture1;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The .Image property set a image as object, you can specify the path o url of the image with ImageLocation

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "PATH O URL OF THE IMAGE";
```